SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'shop_db.vendors.vendor_level' isn't in GROUP BY (Connection:
Internal Server Error
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'shop_db.vendors.vendor_level' isn't in GROUP BY (Connection: mysql, SQL: select vendors.*, COUNT(purchases.id) as purchases_count from vendors inner join purchases on purchases.vendor_id = vendors.id group by vendors.id order by purchases_count desc limit 5)
GET 127.0.0.1:8000
PHP 8.2.12 — Laravel 11.26.0
C:\Users\windows 11\Desktop\marketplace\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php :825
            throw new UniqueConstraintViolationException(
                $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            );
        }

        throw new QueryException(
            $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Determine if the given database exception was caused by a unique constraint violation.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return bool

 */

Request
GET /
Headers
host
127.0.0.1:8000
user-agent
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0
accept
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/png,image/svg+xml,/;q=0.8
accept-language
en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
connection
keep-alive
cookie
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjdodStEY2ZTckxYNkJSNjVDQjJUcGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidTB5blAyMGU1cjl0QVAvQmNVSWdqRlJlM09ZRWNHUEd1MEZhLzR4cUg0Z245Vm1nTmVIQXZZbE1oZG9lakZ6NWYvcUVXdWlIbFJPdzZ4Q1JYQVJ5OUJpaStzOGxnWFE4cHpPUU01cGpicUJKYXRPakorSGRNUmxHQ1hiODVTZ0kiLCJtYWMiOiIwM2RkMGYxOGNmZDc2MzBiNTNkYzBhYmQ1YmJlNGU1MmZjY2EzNGE2YmQwMzdhNDllN2ExM2FhNjc0YTFmMWY1IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlpvQnZRR2ZHc1VwYzR1UUE4N0RhTlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaHBER3Z5djE0VVZxM2xhQ3l2S3FXMTFoWWtiMXJwa1dBV0ZnYUlSUnF2ekdxMDVFa096aEVVUE9jWmpndlZjSzVBWXVobklGeDlTc2hFK1dtUi9pNUtDVWhKSVNoR3k0dkFQTFJFRVViTFB1Nm0zck9aTUlCUytBb2JrRkNmUmwiLCJtYWMiOiJhNDAzYmM4ZDkxYzNjNTIxNTVjMGZiMWZiZmE0NjNiMTBjYzVmODU1ZGJlNDFmMTJkYTcwZGI5NTg3ZjM1ODE5IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D
upgrade-insecure-requests
1
sec-fetch-dest
document
sec-fetch-mode
navigate
sec-fetch-site
none
sec-fetch-user
?1
priority
u=0, i
Body
No body data
Application
Routing
controller
Closure
middleware
web
Database Queries
mysql (3.76 ms)
select * from sessions where id = 'seMACS7ViMEFUnsAQuZoCHbUg4DIQbQIhHfpaFp7' limit 1
mysql (1.59 ms)
select * from cache where key in ('top_vendors_frontpage')
home page to be displayed
